# Unload/Remove vb Resource from Memory

Tags: vb.net

I'm extremely new to programming and have still to master a lot of the basics. But I've managed to make an entire Program with help from here and there. However, I think I've got a Memory Leak with regards to my resources, again I'm new and almost certain this is a clumsy way to go about doing this...

I currently have background music in my application which uses a .wav file stored in My.Resources. I've implemented multiple measures to enable, disable and mute the audio successfully, but  I've hit a snag when I introduced multiple audio tracks. The idea is to give the end-user an option between 4 background songs (stored as 4 .wav resources) in the 'settings' area of my program. When I build & test the solution it runs great, everything as expected. Then when I change the audio to a different track in the settings area, it works also. The snag happens when I change the song multiple times, I get a OutOfMemory error.

I think I understand what's happening; the resource is being added to the memory each time the user selects it, But I have no idea on how to remove -say- song1 from the memory if -say- song2 is selected. Here's my code which handles the selection & playing of the audio.

(The program uses radio buttons *refereed to as '%chkbox'* and requires the user to hit 'savebtn' before this code is ran.) Using Visual Basics 2012 .net 4.5

```
    'Save and start songs.

    If DjErhain_Mistychkbox.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.AudioDJErhain_UWBeats_Maniac = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioDjErhain_Misty = 1
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioMachinimaSound_Exigence = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioSimplex_Memories_master = 0
        My.Settings.Save()

        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.DjErhain_Misty, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)


    ElseIf DJErhain_UWBeats_Maniacckbox.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.AudioDjErhain_Misty = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioDJErhain_UWBeats_Maniac = 1
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioMachinimaSound_Exigence = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioSimplex_Memories_master = 0
        My.Settings.Save()

        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.DJErhain_UWBeats_Maniac, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)


    ElseIf MachinimaSound_Exigencechckbox.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.AudioMachinimaSound_Exigence = 1
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioDJErhain_UWBeats_Maniac = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioDjErhain_Misty = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioSimplex_Memories_master = 0
        My.Settings.Save()

        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.MachinimaSound_Exigence, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)


    ElseIf Simplex_Memories_masterchckbox.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.AudioSimplex_Memories_master = 1
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioDJErhain_UWBeats_Maniac = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioDjErhain_Misty = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.AudioMachinimaSound_Exigence = 0
        My.Settings.Save()

        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Simplex_Memories_master, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)

    Else
    End If
```

Comment: Fist thing to do when fixing a crash is knowing the exact line where it happens (it would be a good exercise for you and would help us to see where the problem is). One thing is sure: the fact of having too many songs in the memory is not the reason (unless you are storing thousands of thousands of millions of songs). Most likely reason: an endless loop was provoked somewhere.

Comment: Nice question and good luck with the project - I think in order to help you, you would have to give more code - namely the entire procedure calling it (or at least which procedure it is) ... From first glance, I can see you are calling My.Settings.Save A LOT and I'm wondering if this is within the `Save` procedure (which could create the endless loop @varocarbas thought was happening). Also, as he states, show us WHER the program breaks to help up understand better what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is likely to go wrong, the .wav format is not very compact.  When you put it in a resource then using the resource is going to create an UnmanagedMemoryStream.  It should be disposed when you don't use it anymore, the garbage collector won't run often enough to keep you out of trouble.

Add a new Module to your project and paste this code:

```
Imports System.IO

Module PlayerUtilities

    Private CurrentStream As WeakReference(Of Stream)

    Public Sub PlayResource(wave As Stream)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(wave, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Dim oldwave As Stream = Nothing
        If CurrentStream IsNot Nothing AndAlso CurrentStream.TryGetTarget(oldwave) Then
            oldwave.Dispose()
        End If
        CurrentStream = New WeakReference(Of Stream)(wave)
    End Sub

End Module
```

And replace your calls to My.Computer.Audio.Play() with PlayResource().  The Dispose() call in this method on the previous audio stream will keep you out of trouble.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! Not only did you give me the code but you explained what was happening. You've been a great help. Thanks for taking your time to answer my question!